# Where does systemd-networkd keep DHCP leases when acting as DHCPServer?

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, systemd-networkd

I've got an ubuntu 22.04 system as my home router/firewall, and I use systemd-networkd as the DHCP server for the LANs.
I have pihole running in a container providing DNS, with the upstream DNS is a dnscrypt-proxy daemon running on the same host.
I use shorewall for the firewalling/NATing.

I want the LAN computers to have their hostnames mapped to their DHCP leases in DNS, and I figure the best way to do this is to parse the DHCP lease database, and append /etc/hosts.  I don't want the pihole to be the DHCP server, and I don't want systemd-resolved to be the DNS server.

Where does systemd-networkd keep the DHCP lease database when acting as a DHCP server? Or is there a better way to get the IP address <-> hostname mapping?

The configuration of the LAN interface:

```
[Match]
MACAddress=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff

[Network]
IPv6PrefixDelegation=dhcpv6
IPv6DuplicateAddressDetection=1
IPv6PrivacyExtensions=yes
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
Address=10.100.10.1/24
DNS=10.100.10.1
DHCPServer=yes
IPv6Token=::1
IPv6SendRA=yes
DHCPv6PrefixDelegation=yes

[DHCPv6PrefixDelegation]
SubnetId=2
Assign=yes

[IPv6PrefixDelegation]
RouterLifetimeSec=900
EmitDNS=yes
DNS=_link_local

[DHCPServer]
EmitDNS=yes
DNS=10.100.10.1
EmitNTP=yes
NTP=10.100.10.1
```

Comment: See `man dhcpd.leases`  https://linux.die.net/man/5/dhcpd.leases

Comment: I'm not using dhcpd, and /var/lib/dhcpd doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

systemd-networkd should store the lease info under /run/systemd/netif/leases/

Comment: Is this in the documentation/man page? Can you provide a hint to how you found this info?

Comment: I looked at the src code https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/fafded0ce0902e948cdeeaa6a12609a28d9c3ded/src/network/networkctl.c#L1663

Answer (score 1):

Summary: need to use DBus to get the property.

The accepted answer here is incorrect; the answer given is for the DHCP *client* leases (received from another DHCP Server).

The source-code link for how `networkctl` reports `Offered DHCP leases` when configured as `DHCPServer=yes` is https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/fafded0ce0902e948cdeeaa6a12609a28d9c3ded/src/network/networkctl.c#L2339

To get *all* leases and isolate just the IP address:

```
$ if=manage; \
  link_id="$(ip --oneline link show dev "$if" | cut -f 1 -d:)"; \
  busctl -j get-property org.freedesktop.network1 \
   "/org/freedesktop/network1/link/${link_id}" \
   org.freedesktop.network1.DHCPServer \
   Leases \
  | jq -r '"\(.data[][2][0]).\(.data[][2][1]).\(.data[][2][2]).\(.data[][2][3])"'
10.254.99.141
```

If there are multiple leases then multiple results will be returned; in which case there needs to be some more complex filtering to also report the client's MAC address in order to identify the correct lease:

```
$ if=manage; \
  link_id="$(ip --oneline link show dev "$if" | cut -f 1 -d:)"; \
  eval "$( \
   busctl -j get-property org.freedesktop.network1 \
   "/org/freedesktop/network1/link/${link_id}" \
   org.freedesktop.network1.DHCPServer \
   Leases \
  | jq -r '[ "printf", "%d.%d.%d.%d %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\\n", \ 
    .data[][2][0], .data[][2][1], .data[][2][2], .data[][2][3], \
    .data[][1][1], .data[][1][2], .data[][1][3], .data[][1][4], .data[][1][5], .data[][1][6] \
           ] | @sh' \
  )"
10.254.99.141 98:DA:C4:C2:EE:80
```

This can be extended to work remotely with a couple of changes: using ssh to 'fetch' the link ID, and adding `busctl --host`:

```
$ if=manage; host="apu2.local"; \
  link_id="$(ssh "$host" ip --oneline link show dev "$if" | cut -f 1 -d:)"; \
 eval "$( \
  busctl --host "$host" -j get-property org.freedesktop.network1 \
  "/org/freedesktop/network1/link/${link_id}" \
  org.freedesktop.network1.DHCPServer \
  Leases \
 | jq -r '[ "printf", "%d.%d.%d.%d %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\\n", \ 
   .data[][2][0], .data[][2][1], .data[][2][2], .data[][2][3], \
   .data[][1][1], .data[][1][2], .data[][1][3], .data[][1][4], .data[][1][5], .data[][1][6] \
          ] | @sh' \
 )"
10.254.99.141 98:DA:C4:C2:EE:80
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on [@ImproviseAdaptOvercome's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1488478/1476628) but uses lower nesting levels so it is hopefully easier to read and paste without quotation issues.

```bash
link_id="$(ip --oneline link show dev "$iface" | cut -f 1 -d:)"
busctl -j get-property org.freedesktop.network1 "/org/freedesktop/network1/link/$link_id" org.freedesktop.network1.DHCPServer Leases \
    | jq -r 'def bytehex:
        [(./16|floor), .%16] | map(if . < 10 then 48 + . else . + 87 end) | implode;
    def formatentry:
        (.[2]|map(tostring)|join(".")) as $ip" | (.[1][1:]|map(bytehex)|join(":")) as $mac | \($ip) \($mac)";
    .data[] | formatentry'
```

It uses pure `jq` to format the result: `bytehex` converts an integer to hexadecimal, and `formatentry` converts each record to a string. One can easily change the output format for downstream processing.